# Updating SMS sending result from AWS SNS Client

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I send the SMS messages successfully with AWS SNS Client, based on this guide: [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html#sms_publish_sdk)
My problem is that I want to update the result of this message sending.
I got the Message Id returned by the client and I store it in DB.

So my approach would be to create a scheduled job that would check my message sending results. Go through my database for messages that didn't have any result and query them from AWS. But I can't find any way to get the result from java code. I can check the metrics but that only gives me statistics results. I saw that there is a service called AWS Insight but I can't find any guide/docs about how to use it from the SDK. Maybe my approach is wrong, so I welcome any idea :)

Comment: 1) Using Java SDK to query AWS CloudWatch as you mentioned in the question;
  a) Use [AWSLogsClient.startQuery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/AWSLogsClient.html#startQuery-com.amazonaws.services.logs.model.StartQueryRequest-) with your AWS CloudWatch insight query and keep note of queryId.
  b) Use [AWSLogsClient.getQueryResults](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/AWSLogsClient.html#getQueryResults-com.amazonaws.services.logs.model.GetQueryResultsRequest-) using queryId from 1.a)

Comment: OR

2) In case you are fine with SMS delivery updates per 24 hours. Then [daily SMS usage csv format reports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_usage.html) on AWS S3 is an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be several options depends up which AWS resources you are using but not mentioned in the question or AWS resources which can help you to trace what you are looking for.

With reference to current information in your question. Following are some of the options;

1. Using Java SDK to query AWS CloudWatch as you mentioned in the question;
   a) Use [AWSLogsClient.startQuery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/AWSLogsClient.html#startQuery-com.amazonaws.services.logs.model.StartQueryRequest-) with your AWS CloudWatch insight query and keep note/store queryId.
   b) Use [AWSLogsClient.getQueryResults](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/AWSLogsClient.html#getQueryResults-com.amazonaws.services.logs.model.GetQueryResultsRequest-) using queryId from 1.a) to view AWS CloudWatch execution results.

OR

2. In case you are fine with SMS delivery updates per 24 hours. Then [daily SMS usage csv format reports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_usage.html) on AWS S3 is an option. Moreover, you can [query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/SelectObjectContentUsingJava.html) these reports on AWS S3 or [download](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingJava.html) report and extract information out of it as per your use-case.

Comment: It looks like I choose a third way. I will pump the logs with AWS lambda to an endpoint in my application :) But your are working solutions as well.